# Amazon Limited Permission for Specific Image Launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a user and provided him with the following permissions. I want that user to only be able to launch AMIs with specific tag key/values ("Open"). But the user gets "Initialization Failed" during launch instance from image.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1434563026000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ImgEnv": "Open"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*"
            ]
        },
        {

            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:Describe*",
              "ec2:*Vpc*",
              "ec2:*Subnet*",
              "ec2:*Gateway*",
              "ec2:*Vpn*",
              "ec2:*Route*",
              "ec2:*Address*",
              "ec2:*SecurityGroup*",
              "ec2:*NetworkAcl*",
              "ec2:*DhcpOptions*" ],

            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a policy that should work for you (make sure to replace 'account' with your account ID and change the region if you're not using us-east-1):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1::image/ami-*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/ImgEnv": "Open"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:key-pair/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:account:security-group/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I think that structuring the policy like this is necessary because not all resources in the RunInstances context need to be (or are) tagged. Just the image.

I found http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html useful when checking and testing this answer.

P.S. I focussed on your RunInstances permission. You should still add more policy to permit the Describe/other APIs you want, e.g.

```
    {

        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["ec2:Describe*",
          "ec2:*Vpc*",
          "ec2:*Subnet*",
          "ec2:*Gateway*",
          "ec2:*Vpn*",
          "ec2:*Route*",
          "ec2:*Address*",
          "ec2:*SecurityGroup*",
          "ec2:*NetworkAcl*",
          "ec2:*DhcpOptions*" ],

        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

Comment: You need to give me more details. Like the output of your RunInstances command in debug mode. And a copy of the policy you used please. This should work. It did for me.

Comment: I am not using cli , i am using interface , I want to create a user like User1 . and i want to provide him only instance launch permission from My AMI those key  Value production = open .  I use your solutions but its show initialization failed .

Comment: I provide my all details in another Post Please see it .[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032559/amazon-ec2-tag-based-launch-permission)